# Basic XOR encryption + byte substraction (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple XOR encryption routine in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013343/simple-xor-encryption-routine-in-c-c)

Sorry, was double-post. Delete pls.

Comment: Basic it is, encryption it's not!

Comment: 0xC5 in ASM, 0xC4 in C++ code

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013343/simple-xor-encryption-routine-in-c-c

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a different question. All students in the same class I'll guess.

Answer (score 0):

If `filesize` is the size of the buffer `filebuffer` than accessing `filebuffer[filesize]` is a mistake. This is what you do in the first iteration of the loop when `i == filesize`.
The last element of the buffer is `filebuffer[filesize-1]` and this is where your loop should start.

This error may potentially cause your code to crash but it may or may not be what's causing this to misbehave. Can you elaborate on what you see is "wrong" with the result?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state what doesn't work, but I suspect the problem is an off-by one error. Instead of:

```
for ( i = filesize; i > 0; i-- )
```

you should do:

```
for ( i = filesize - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
```

(Array subscripts start at 0, not 1)

Comment: Oh, thanks DarkDust!! Works now like a charm :)