# Easy way to encrypt a text file

Tags: c++, text, encode

I'm working on a text based adventure game in C++ and I would like to store quests in a text file,but I don't want the player to read it.

Is there an easy way to encrypt it?

Comment: Do you want to encode it or hide it? Quite different things.

Comment: Unless you are writing in C++ *and* the [RPG language](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahg/rzahgrpgcode.htm) you should not use the [tag:RPG] tag. Please read what a tag means on this site before using it, and the definition pops up making it dead simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to "hide" content of your file to player is to encrypt the file.

You can use [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/) for instance.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007337/encrypting-and-decrypting-a-small-file-using-openssl) thread you can have an idea on the usage.

Answer (score 0):

Velthune's OpenSSL suggestion is fine but it is arguably overkill. I would try something simple like [XOR encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013343/simple-xor-encryption-routine-in-c-c) instead.

Of course XOR encryption is **not secure**, but neither is the OpenSSL approach, since your program must store the encryption key somewhere in the executable file in order to be able to do the decryption.

**There is no way to truly secure the file's contents against a determined user and still have it be accessible to a program that runs on the user's machine.**

So, I'd suggest XOR encryption as a simple form of obfuscation that will deter someone from changing the file casually, yet won't make your program dependent on an external library.

Comment: To put it another way: you don't need a top-of-the-line lock on your front door if you're going to be leaving the key under the mat. A cheap look is probably good enough. :-)

Comment: And here's a simple program to do that for you on windows , it comes with source code so you can build it for your platform  https://sourceforge.net/projects/xorencrypt2/